# Is there a way to view the solr indexing on the go

Tags: indexing, solr, live, status

I am indexing big files on solr, which takes a small amount of time, i want to see how much records have been inserted and how much are remaining

Comment: What tool are you using to upload data to Solr?

Comment: query to solr and will give you the numFound which tells you the records been indexed...I assume you already know how many files are there for indexing'

Comment: I'm uploading data using curl request

Comment: Yes, i do know the  total number of records, i want to know how many records are added at any given moment, just like when we download something, we get to know 10mb downloaded and so on

Comment: Either make your script that uses curl to upload content tell you how many files it has uploaded, or query the index while indexing to see how many documents have been added (.. requires a commit to be visible to regular queries, so it'll depend on how you're indexing).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out

Comment: @MatsLindh, Thanks for your suggestion, i wrote a python script fetching numFound in while loop and printing the number of new records added